# Jar cannot be run via double click on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I have exported a javafx program from Eclipse as a runable jar, and if I run it from either eclipse or the command line it runs fine. but when I try to run it by double clicking it I get a warning saying that it could not be launched, and to check the console for possible error messages.

I have attempted the below solution:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/how-do-i-run-a-jar-when-i-double-click-it
But it just tells me that /dev/null does not exist.

A similar issue had popped up on my windows computer, and was caused by the computer attempting to use an different version of java when I double clicked vs what appears in the command line when I type java -version.

An older version of the program was able to run perfectly fine when double clicked as well.

Does anyone have any solutions for how to update my Mac's java version, or otherwise make the jar runable?

Edit:
[Link to screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH0DO.png)

Comment: Mind showing a picture of the error/message you're getting upon clicking?

Comment: Link to picture is at the bottom now.

Comment: Alright, now show an image of the successful output after running the jar in a console.

Comment: Nothing shows up in the console, it just displays the GUI for my program.